# Problem with passing pointer to function in C

Tags: c, pointers

This is one of those annoying things where you know the answer is easy, but you just can't see it.

The `printf` statement in `AllocIntArray` shows that `arrayPtr` is correctly being assigned a memory location, however when the `printf` statement in main is run, it shows `arrayB` is still set to `NULL`.

Can someone show me what I am doing wrong when passing in `arrayB` to `AllocIntArray`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void AllocIntArray(int *arrayPtr, int numElements);

int main()
{
   int *arrayB = NULL;

   AllocIntArray(arrayB, 10);
   printf("Pointer: %p\n", arrayB);

   free(arrayB);

   getchar();
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void AllocIntArray(int *arrayPtr, int numElements)
{
   arrayPtr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * numElements);
   printf("Pointer: %p\n", arrayPtr);

   if(arrayPtr == NULL)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "\nError allocating memory using malloc");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}
```

Comment: I think you arg arrayPtr should be pointer-to-pointer to be able to allocate and see outside it's function scope.  so `int **arrayPtr`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the double pointer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void AllocIntArray(int **arrayPtr, int numElements);

int main()
{
   int *arrayB = NULL;

   AllocIntArray(&arrayB, 10);
   printf("Pointer: %p\n", arrayB);

   free(arrayB);

   getchar();
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void AllocIntArray(int **arrayPtr, int numElements)
{
   *arrayPtr = malloc(sizeof(int) * numElements);
   printf("Pointer: %p\n", *arrayPtr);

   if(*arrayPtr == NULL)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "\nError allocating memory using malloc");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
}
```

Comment: +1, but I hesitated - please don't cast malloc return values.

Comment: @paxdiablo, isn't that just a matter of programmer preference?

Comment: @Chris, casting it can hide certain errors and warnings from the compiler, which will make your life more difficult. For example: http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?id=1043284351&answer=1047673478

Comment: When programming, never do things you don't know the reasons behind. Casting the result from malloc is one of those things. Most of the time people cast it without thinking because their _C++ compiler_ gave a warning... that is, they are using the wrong compiler and hides it behind explicit type casts.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `arrayB` is passed to `AllocIntArray` by value. Either pass it by reference (with a pointer-to-pointer), or better, return it from `AllocIntArray`:

```
int *AllocIntArray(int numElements)
{
   int *arrayPtr = malloc(sizeof(int) * numElements);
   printf("Pointer: %p\n", arrayPtr);

   if(arrayPtr == NULL)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "\nError allocating memory using malloc");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   return arrayPtr;
}
```

Comment: Another good way of doing it (especially if it avoids the problems most newbies have with indirect pointers. But, again, why are you casting the return from `malloc`?

Comment: @paxdiablo: I copy-pasted the OP's code and made minimal changes to it to demonstrate my intentions. Removed the `malloc` return cast as well.

Answer (score 0):

`arrayPtr` is a pointer and the *pointer* is passed by *value* to the parameter. `AllocIntArray` can modify its version of `arrayPtr` but the changes won't be seen by `main()`.

(Edit: if you're using C++) modifying the signature for `AllocIntArray` to change the type of `arrayPtr` to a reference ought to fix your problem.

```
void AllocIntArray(int *&arrayPtr, int numElements)
```

Comment: WTF is `*&`? You better not be trying to corrupt my beautiful C language with your C++ shenanigans :-)

Comment: Ahh... sorry. Tag my answer 'c++'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to brush up a bit on parameter passing to functions.

The pointer you are sending to AllocIntArray is being copied into arrayPtr, The line

```
   arrayPtr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * numElements);
```

assigns a value into the copy, and not the original variable, and therefore the original variable still points to nowhere.

First solution that comes to mind is to send a pointer to that pointer, but I think you'd best do some general brushing up on the matter of parameter passing before going much further.

Comment: I just haven't done much pointer to a pointer excercises in my class work so far, thus using it here eluded me. Once seeing it, it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem here is you are passing `arrayB` to `AllocIntArray` function as passed by value .In `AllocIntArray` its allocating memory properly and `arrayptr` is valid but in `main` function its not the same memory which you are expecting .
This is the basic C programming concept and you can check bu adding print in both the function .

EX: I am sharing the difference between both problem and success case with below example .

```
/*Code with passed by value as a parameter*/ 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void AllocateIntarray(int *arrayptr,int numElements)
{
     arrayptr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*numElements);
     printf("Inside _func_AllocateIntarray_pointer:%p\n",arrayptr);

     if(arrayptr == NULL)
     {
         printf("ERR_MEM_ALLOCATION_FAILED:\n");
     }
}

int main()
{
     int *arrayB = NULL;
     AllocateIntarray(arrayB,10);
     printf("Inside _func_mainPointer:%p\n",arrayB);

     free(arrayB);
     return 0;
 }
/*Output :
 Inside _func_AllocateIntarray_pointer:0x55be51f96260
 Inside _func_mainPointer:(nil)*/
```

Code with Passed by reference and using  double pointer  .

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void AllocateIntarray(int **arrayptr,int numElements)
{
     *arrayptr =  malloc(sizeof(int)*numElements);
     printf("Inside _func_AllocateIntarray_pointer:%p\n",*arrayptr);

     if(*arrayptr == NULL)
     {
          printf("ERR_MEM_ALLOCATION_FAILED:\n");
     }
 }
 int main()
 {
     int *arrayB = NULL;
     AllocateIntarray(&arrayB,10);
     printf("Inside _func_mainPointer:%p\n",arrayB);

     free(arrayB);
     return 0;
  }
  /*Output :
    Inside _func_AllocateIntarray_pointer:0x562bacd1f260
    Inside _func_mainPointer:0x562bacd1f260*/
```